# What does the javax.servlet.http.Part stand for?

Tags: java, servlets

What does [Part](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/Part.html) stand for? And which http request will reduce Parts that can be fetched by [HttpServletRequest#getParts()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts()) method?

Please give a example, thanks.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2 has both explanation and examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It represents the chunks of a HTTP request that was sent with Content-Type `multipart/form-data`. It can therefore be anything, as each part has its own Content-Type and name, so traditional request parameters, JSON, XML, and that's how files are uploaded.

Comment: it will help you catch uploaded files to server , like html  <input type="file">